# Azure VM backup before schedule time or incorrect timing

Tags: azure, azure-vm, azure-backup-vault

We have setup Azure VM backup daily at 15:00 PM. But it is taking backup mostly around 14:10 and rarely around 15:00. Is this timing difference expected?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your VM's backup policy? Note that Azure Backup doesn't support automatic clock adjustment for daylight-saving changes for Azure VM backups. As time changes occur, modify backup policies manually as required.

Comment: Question is not about day light savings time chnge. Will post the screenshot later